# League of Legends Chatroom and Ranked Team (EUW)

Tags: discussion, community

A number of League of Legends players have been hanging out in the chatroom [Summoners Rift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift).

We've also created a ranked team called *"Arqade Community"*, on the EUW servers.

We're trying to set up an in-game chat channel called *"ArqadeCommunity"* (No spaces) but so far it isn't seeing much activity since it doesn't record messages people miss while not logged into the game. For now the best way to arrange things is to use the Summoners Rift chat room on this site.

We've players ranging from Silver through to Diamond so whatever your skill level come and say hi. LoL is fun playing with people you know :)

Comment: Please call the in game channel something else

Comment: @badp Removed reference to the in game channel, I didn't set it up (and it's not used much)

Comment: Use a chat called "Arqade Community" like your team name; we just want to avoid confusing "official" places with "fan" places.

Comment: There's no one in that "Arquade Community" channel =(

Comment: @Oak It's a ranked team, not a channel. We did have a channel but we've been asked to change the name and I don't think anyone has yet. Best bet is to hang out in the summoners rift chat room on this site, and then people can add you to their friends lists and arrange games that way.

Comment: Thought it was both , my bad =)

Comment: @Oak I've just added the info for the new channel, you may well be the first person to use it though :)

Comment: First
#yolo
(Sffc)

Comment: 3v3 bronze 1 hype!!!

it's so much fun to play with you guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

I thought ranked team was only 5 players - or is it there are only 5 Arqade members of a similar skill level on EUW :)

Imho, while having 'Arqade' in a name **in LoL** makes sense, the chat room is on Arqade site already so its better to call it 'LoL chat' or something.

Comment: Ranked team can have up to 10 players, only 3 or 5 can play in each match.

Comment: The chat room on Arqade is called Summoners Rift. The one in game is called ArquadeCommunity

Comment: @TimB I misread the part about ingame chat, thanks :)

Comment: @TimB Is it "ArquadeCommunity" or "ArqadeCommunity"? The latter is the correct spelling.